# Magento checkout broken in IE9 and IE8 for that matter

Tags: magento, prototypejs

Magento checkout broken in IE9 and IE8 for that matter

When testing our checkout in Magento we ran into this strange error with IE9 when opening the following page (maybe first select a product)

http://shirtsofholland.com/checkout/onepage/

SAME AS: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/267307/

Any help appreciated, debugged alotta things. No solution yet

Comment: Maybe you should describe the error. Linking to a site that is about to be changed will do no good for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened was that the plugin Crius Skipstep (hiding whole login section) was breaking the layout code.

We resolved by stopping the extension & logging an issue at their site
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/skip-checkout-step-1.html

Thanks for your answer philwinkle (I am sure this works for many other cases!)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue. Easiest fix as of now is to direct IE to operate in non-compatibility mode, operating at IE7. See below for a well-publicized forum thread of this issue:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/211267/

The best you can do is use the .htaccess fix. It's the quickest and least-intrusive way and according to Magento Support the suggested solution. You can find the full write-up here (http://www.pauldonnellydesigns.com/blog/magento-ie9-issue-fix/) but the gist is below:

**Add to .htaccess:**

```
BrowserMatch MSIE best-standards-support
Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=8 env=best-standards-support
```

Comment: I was hoping this would do the trick. But nope. Doesnt fix it for me. Many thanks. The page still is garbled looking